# Order items: A, B, AA, AB

Tags: powershell

Having difficulties ordering items...

I'm trying to process a file, with the end results that items are uploaded into SharePoint in the correct order.

Within the data (CSV) that I need to process, I have a column called `Version`, this is piece of text limited to two characters. The first Version is `A`, ranging to `ZZ`.

A normal item may look like this. Here, there are three versions of item 1 and I can sort them by Ascending on the Version Column.

```
Title: item 1
Version: A

Title: item 1
Version: B

Title: item 1
Version: C
```

**The issue**

```
Title: item 2
Version: A

Title: item 2
Version: B

...... many versions later ....

Title: item 2
Version: AA

Title: item 2
Version: AB
```

Using the sort expression of Ascending on 'Version', this will be sorted in the following order:

```
A
AA
AB
B
```

When I need the order to be:

```
A
B
AA
AB
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve the above?

Comment: `Sort-Object { $_.Version.Length }, Version`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left-pad with a space, it'll precede `A` in alphabetical sort order:

```
$sortedByVersion = $items |Sort -Property {$_.Version.PadLeft(2,' ')}
```

---

Here's an example using bare strings:

```
PS C:\> "a","b","c","aa","bb","cc"|Sort-Object
a
aa
b
bb
c
cc
PS C:\> "a","b","c","aa","bb","cc"|Sort-Object {$_.PadLeft(2,' ')}
a
b
c
aa
bb
cc
```

Comment: Excellent, there's always a simple solution! Thanks.

Comment: This is awesome mathias :)